# Do HP Elitebooks allow to switch off Optimus from BIOS?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, optimus, hp-elitebook

I'm checking which HP EliteBook (among 8740w,8760w) gives the possibility to switch off Optimus in the BIOS (need it to simplify CUDA development under Ubuntu). Or even better, **is there a list of the laptops allowing this switch off**?  Soon I'll buy a laptop, so I'd like to have this info. I'm aware of the existence of Bumblebee, but if I can make my life easier..

Thank you for the help!

Martina

p.s. Right now, I'm just sure that Lenovo ThinkPad does have this switch-off

Comment: So, what (Optimus-wise on EliteBooks) did you discover after buying it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a fix for Ubuntu, but I CAN help you, if you are using Windows as well. Right-click on the Desktop and choose "NVIDIA Control Panel". Then, when in the Control Panel, click on "Manage 3D Settings". You'll have three options: **Auto-select** (will enable NVIDIA), **High-Performance** (will enable NVIDIA and use its full potential; good for graphics rendering), **Integrated Graphics** (this is what your Control Panel should be set to if you have the problem you just described). Turn on either the first or the second option.

I'm sorry that I can't provide you with Ubuntu tutorial. However, taking into account that you are probably very experienced with this particular OS, I think you should be able to follow my tutorial anyway.

[Here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03519217) is a more detailed description for Windows. To my knowledge, BIOS will not help you here. HP EliteBooks are known for ridiculously handicapped BIOSes. I hope my reply helped you out! Have a nice day!

P.S.: I tested my claims on my HP EliteBook 8760w. I can't guarantee that the fix will work on another system (and possibly OS in your case).

Comment: sorry man, the question is 4 years old and I can't test anymore your procedure (no more working on GPGPU and moreover I'm on iOS). Thank you anyway, your answer can be useful for other people though!